# How to get selected text and start and end locations using PySide & QTextEdit?

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I'm able to display a QTextEdit widget and detect when the user changes the selected text. However, I'm unsure how to get the selected text and the integer values that represent the start and end locations of the selection measured as the number of characters from the beginning of the text field. Do I need to create a QTextCursor? I'd appreciate an example. Here is my current code:

```
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

class Form(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("My Form")
        self.edit = QTextEdit("Type here...")
        self.button = QPushButton("Show Greetings")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.greetings)
        self.quit = QPushButton("QUIT")
        self.quit.clicked.connect(app.exit)
        self.edit.selectionChanged.connect(self.handleSelectionChanged)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.quit)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def greetings(self):
        print ("Hello %s" % self.edit.text())

    def handleSelectionChanged(self):
        print ("Selection start:%d end%d" % (0,0)) # change to position & anchor

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form=Form()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with selection within `QTextEdit` via `QTextCursor`, yes. It has [selectionStart](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextcursor.html#selectionStart) and [selectionEnd](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextcursor.html#selectionEnd) methods which you should use:

```
def handleSelectionChanged(self):
    cursor = self.edit.textCursor()
    print ("Selection start: %d end: %d" % 
           (cursor.selectionStart(), cursor.selectionEnd()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the start, en and ho to get the text.

```
        cursor = self.edit.textCursor()
        start = cursor.selectionStart()
        end = cursor.selectionEnd()
        self.lbl_status.setText('Selected Count: ' + str(end - start))

        txt = self.edit.textCursor().selectedText()
```